# Exception in getting connection for Teradata datasource

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbc, teradata

I am trying to inject Datasource in my Controller and using that(datasource) I want connection object. I am using spring boot
I have written two configuration class one for Oracle connection and other for Teradata connection

For oracle everything works fine but for creating teradata datasource I wasn't not able to fine any good example so here is how my configuration looks like:

```
@Component
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("application")
public class TeradataConfiguration {


@NotNull
    private String usernameTeradata;
@NotNull
private String passwordTeradata;

@NotNull
private String servernameTeradata;

@NotNull
private String charsetTeradata;

@NotNull
private String tmodeTeradata;

@NotNull
private String dsnameTeradata;

@NotNull
private String portTeradata;

@NotNull
private String timeoutTeradata;


public void setUsernameTeradata(String usernameTeradata) {
    this.usernameTeradata = usernameTeradata;
}


public void setPasswordTeradata(String passwordTeradata) {
    this.passwordTeradata = passwordTeradata;
}


public void setServernameTeradata(String servernameTeradata) {
    this.servernameTeradata = servernameTeradata;
}


public void setCharsetTeradata(String charsetTeradata) {
    this.charsetTeradata = charsetTeradata;
}


public void setTmodeTeradata(String tmodeTeradata) {
    this.tmodeTeradata = tmodeTeradata;
}


public void setDsnameTeradata(String dsnameTeradata) {
    this.dsnameTeradata = dsnameTeradata;
}


public void setPortTeradata(String portTeradata) {
    this.portTeradata = portTeradata;
}


public void setTimeoutTeradata(String timeoutTeradata) {
    this.timeoutTeradata = timeoutTeradata;
}


@Bean
DataSource teraDataSource() throws SQLException {

    TeraDataSource teraDataSource = new TeraDataSource();
    teraDataSource.setServerName(dsnameTeradata);
    teraDataSource.setuser(usernameTeradata);
    teraDataSource.setpassword(passwordTeradata);
    teraDataSource.setCharSet(charsetTeradata);
    teraDataSource.setTMODE(tmodeTeradata);
    teraDataSource.setDSName(dsnameTeradata);
    teraDataSource.setDbsPort(portTeradata);
    teraDataSource.setLoginTimeout(Integer.valueOf(timeoutTeradata));
    return teraDataSource;

}
```

}

After this I have injected this bean into my controller but when I am doing:

```
teraDataSource.getConnection();
```

I am getting below exception:

```
    TERAJDBC4 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-1] 

    com.teradata.jdbc.jdk6.JDK6_SQL_Connection@fc561d Connection to TEST_DB Fri Oct 05 16:03:10 IST 2018 socket orig=TEST_DB cid=28fb20be sess=0 java.net.UnknownHostException: TEST_DB   at 
java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)   at 
java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)   at 
java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)   
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1276)   at 
java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192)   at 
java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)   at 
com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.io.TDNetworkIOIF$Lookup.doLookup(TDNetworkIOIF.ja
va:223)   at 
com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.io.TDNetworkIOIF$Lookup.getAddresses(TDNetworkIOI
F.java:261)   at 
com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.io.TDNetworkIOIF.connectToHost(TDNetworkIOIF.java
:381)   at 
com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.io.TDNetworkIOIF.createSocketConnection(TDNetwork
IOIF.java:156)   at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.io.TDNetworkIOIF.<init>
(TDNetworkIOIF.java:142)   at 
com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.GenericTeradataConnection.getIO(GenericTeradataConn
ection.java:143)   at 
com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.GenericLogonController.run(GenericLogonController.j
ava:100)   at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDSession.<init>
(TDSession.java:211)   at com.teradata.jdbc.jdk6.JDK6_SQL_Connection.
<init>(JDK6_SQL_Connection.java:36)   at 
com.teradata.jdbc.jdk6.JDK6ConnectionFactory.constructSQLConnection(JDK6Co
nnectionFactory.java:25)   at 
com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactor
y.java:181)   at 
com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactor
y.java:171)   at 
com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDataSourceBase.createNewConnection(TeraDataSourceBas
e.java:696)   at 
com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDataSource.getConnection(TeraDataSource.java:21)   
at 
com.test.dnb.dao.CompanyProfileDAO.writeToTeradataTable(CompanyProfileDAO.
java:1052)   at 
com.test.dnb.application.Controller.companyFamilyFullTree(Controller.java:
641)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:
62)   at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorIm
pl.java:43)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)   at 
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(Inv
ocableHandlerMethod.java:205)   at 
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForReq
uest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)   at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHand
lerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)   at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandle
rAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)   at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandle
rAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)   at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.ha
ndle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)   at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherSer
vlet.java:967)   at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServ
let.java:901)   at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkS
ervlet.java:970)   at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.ja
va:861)   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)   
at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.
java:846)   at 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)   at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Applicati
onFilterChain.java:231)   at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilter
Chain.java:166)   at 
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)   
at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Applicati
onFilterChain.java:193)   at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilter
Chain.java:166)   at 
org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(Reque
stContextFilter.java:99)   at 
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerReques
tFilter.java:107)   at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Applicati
onFilterChain.java:193)   at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilter
Chain.java:166)   at 
org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(H
ttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)   at 
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerReques
tFilter.java:107)   at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Applicati
onFilterChain.java:193)   at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilter
Chain.java:166)   at 
org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(Hid
denHttpMethodFilter.java:81)   at 
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerReques
tFilter.java:107)   at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Applicati
onFilterChain.java:193)   at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilter
Chain.java:166)   at 
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(Ch
aracterEncodingFilter.java:197)   at 
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerReques
tFilter.java:107)   at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Applicati
onFilterChain.java:193)   at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilter
Chain.java:166)   at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.
java:199)   at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.
java:96)   at 
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBa
se.java:504)   at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:1
40)   at 
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:8
1)   at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.ja
va:87)   at 
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342
)   at 
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
   at 
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.ja
va:66)   at 
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProto
col.java:790)   at 
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.j
ava:1459)   at 
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.jav
a:49)   at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:
1149)   at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java
:624)   at 
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.
java:61)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Below are the properties that I am using:

```
> application.servernameTeradata=server.com
> application.usernameTeradata=user 
> application.passwordTeradata=pass
> application.charsetTeradata=UTF8 
> application.tmodeTeradata=ANSI
> application.dsnameTeradata=TEST_DB 
> application.portTeradata=1025
> application.timeoutTeradata=180000
```

I am able to connect to teradata via normal jdbc using Class.forName("Driver Name") but facing issue with datasource.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace; what you have posted now seems to be just somewhere in the middle of the stacktrace, which makes it uninformative. And please fix the formatting: use a code block for your properties; it is hard to read because you used a quote block.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I have added complete stack trace please take a look

Comment: This: _java.net.UnknownHostException: TEST_DB_ seems to indicate that you have your connection config mixed up; it tries to connect to a database server with the name `TEST_DB`, while I think you intend that as the database name and not the server name. You may want to review the documentation of `TeraDataSource` to see how you should map your properties.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks for pointing the connection part out and also for the suggestion I looked at the documentation and after testing few combinations finally got this code to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some R&D and Mark's help I was able to make the configuration work. I am posting the solution so that other's can be benefited from the answer.

If you have teradata url like this : jdbc:teradata://server_name/database=database_nane,tmode=ANSI,charset=UTF8

The datasource configuration file should look like this:

```
@Component
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("application")
public class TeradataConfiguration {

    @NotNull
    private String usernameTeradata;

    @NotNull
    private String passwordTeradata;

    @NotNull
    private String servernameTeradata;

    @NotNull
    private String charsetTeradata;

    @NotNull
    private String tmodeTeradata;

    @NotNull
    private String dsnameTeradata;

    @NotNull
    private String portTeradata;

    public void setUsernameTeradata(String usernameTeradata) {
        this.usernameTeradata = usernameTeradata;
    }


    public void setPasswordTeradata(String passwordTeradata) {
        this.passwordTeradata = passwordTeradata;
    }


    public void setServernameTeradata(String servernameTeradata) {
        this.servernameTeradata = servernameTeradata;
    }


    public void setCharsetTeradata(String charsetTeradata) {
        this.charsetTeradata = charsetTeradata;
    }


    public void setTmodeTeradata(String tmodeTeradata) {
        this.tmodeTeradata = tmodeTeradata;
    }


    public void setDsnameTeradata(String dsnameTeradata) {
        this.dsnameTeradata = dsnameTeradata;
    }


    public void setPortTeradata(String portTeradata) {
        this.portTeradata = portTeradata;
    }

    @Bean
    DataSource teraDataSource() throws SQLException {

        TeraDataSource teraDataSource = new TeraDataSource();
        //This is username
        teraDataSource.setuser(usernameTeradata);
        //This is password
        teraDataSource.setpassword(passwordTeradata);
        //Charset which could be UTF-8 or something else
        teraDataSource.setCharSet(charsetTeradata);
        //Tmode which could be ANSII or something else
        teraDataSource.setTMODE(tmodeTeradata);
        //This is your server name
        teraDataSource.setDSName(servernameTeradata);
        //This is teradata port which by default is 1025
        teraDataSource.setDbsPort(portTeradata);
        //This is your data base name
        teraDataSource.setDatabaseName(dsnameTeradata);
        return teraDataSource;

    }
}
```

After this just inject this bean into your class and just do

```
teraDataSource.getConnection()
```

This will give you teradata connection.

Comment: this was really helpful, I was wondering what one would do if they need to connect to three different teradata databases would have to do something with using the datasourceName ?